# Check if a user is online codeigniter without using sessions using time() instead

Tags: codeigniter

When my user logs in it updates the last_active and last_visit width `time()`.

Once user has logged on any page that is visits it updates the users **last_active** and **last_visit** column.

I am trying to figure out the best way so on the users profile page it can show if user is online or not even if in different browser.

```
http://sample.com/user/1
```

I can not seem to get it correct. It still shows user as online in other browsers when infact the user has logged out

> **Question** how can I check if the user is online or not even if in a
>   different browser?

I have looked at [How to see if a user is online in a website with php and mysql driven databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026263/how-to-see-if-a-user-is-online-in-a-website-with-php-and-mysql-driven-databases)

And [PHP Check if a user is online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504344/php-check-if-a-user-is-online)

The links not help.

```
if(date("H:i:s", $udata['last_active']) == date("H:i:s", $udata['last_visit']) && date("H:i:s", $udata['last_active']) != date("H:i:s", strtotime("+1 min"))) {
    $this->data['active'] = 1;
} else {
    $this->data['active'] = 0;
}
```

Model

```
<?php 

class User_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

        if ($this->islogged() == 1) {

            $this->db->where('user_id', $this->getuserid());
            $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix  . 'user_data');

            if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {

                $user_data = array(
                    'last_active' => time(),
                    'last_visit' => time(),
                    'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address()
                );

                $this->db->where('user_id', $query->row()->user_id);
                $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_data', $user_data);
            }

        } else {

            $this->logout();
        }
    }

}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class User extends MY_Controller {

    public $data;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('elapsed_time');
        $this->load->model('forum/thread_model');
        $this->load->model('user/user_model');
    }

    public function index($user_id) {
        $udata = $this->user_model->getuser($user_id);

        if ($udata) {

            // Titles
            $this->data['title'] = 'Profile of ' . $udata['username'];
            $this->data['heading_title'] = 'Forum Info';

            // Page Data
            $this->data['profile_username'] = $udata['username'];

            if(date("H:i:s", $udata['last_active']) == date("H:i:s", $udata['last_visit']) && date("H:i:s", $udata['last_active']) != date("H:i:s", strtotime("+1 min"))) {
                $this->data['active'] = 1;
            } else {
                $this->data['active'] = 0;
            }

            $this->data['how_long_was_online'] = 'Created account but not logged in yet!';
            $this->data['date_created'] = date('d-m-Y h:i:s' , $udata['date_created']);

            $this->data['avatar'] = ($udata['avatar']) ? $udata['avatar'] : 'holder.js/100px180';

            $this->data['total_questions'] = $this->thread_model->total_users_thread_questions($user_id);
            $this->data['total_threads'] = $this->thread_model->total_users_threads($user_id);

            // Page Links
            $this->data['users_questions'] = site_url('search/questions/' . $user_id);
            $this->data['users_threads'] = site_url('search/threads/' . $user_id);
            $this->data['pm'] = site_url('mail/pm/' . $user_id);
            $this->data['email'] = site_url('mail/email/' . $user_id);

            $this->data['children'] = array(
                'common/header',
                'common/footer',
                'common/navbar' 
            );

            $this->load->render('user/user', $this->data);

        } else {

            redirect('not_found');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960396/users-online-codeigniter-and-sessions

Comment: Sorry no @ChrisChen not what I am after not using sessions for that check I am using time() from the users profile.

Comment: If you last active time is a unix timestamp in seconds can you make the assumption that after 15 minutes of last active time, they off-line? Like, `if ($udata['last_active'] + (15 * 60) > time()) { $this->data['active'] = 1 } else { $this->data['active'] = 0 };`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 to be honest using time count in server to watch the session is not a good idea because of many reasons. You'd rather setup a Interval using javascript on client side so your user will keep beeping your server to claim their are alive. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051895/whats-the-easiest-way-to-determine-if-a-user-is-online-php-mysql